# Any way to prevent lightheadedness when getting up?

Tags: dizziness

Sometimes when I get up from lying down or sitting position I feel lightheaded. I can also get ringing in my ears and/or dizziness. It goes away on its own after about a minute. If I get up slowly it can help prevent those symptoms.

I'm wondering if there's any other way to prevent this from happening or an explanation of why it might happen. I've asked my doctor about this in the past who didn't really have an answer other than suggesting I get up slowly. I've had tests (blood, heart, blood pressure) that show everything is fine. I'm a male in my early 30s who is otherwise healthy. I've had these symptoms for about 10 years.

Comment: This is a question that requires an individualized diagnosis.  The fact you've had a workup is reassuring but we can't say one way or another without knowing the tests that were/weren't done and the results and your medical history and meds and family history and other symptoms and vitals and orthostatics and... none of that can happen here.  So it's got to be your doctor who advises you, or it's not safe. Did the doctors give you advice how to treat the symptoms?  If not, go back and ask them specifically how to manage it.  Make sure they know you still have these symptoms.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone gets dizzy to some degree when they get up *suddenly* from a supine position (laying down) or even sitting. When significant, this is called orthostatic hypotension. The most common cause in a 'normal' person is because the veins in your legs hold more blood proportionally lying down than when standing and walking. When you suddenly stand, the blood returning to your heart in insufficient to supply your brain *momentarily* (i.e. your *cardiac output* decreases.) The answer is, indeed, getting up slowly.

In addition, keeping well hydrated may help; Since in a supine position the venous capacitance is high, move the muscles in your legs - all of them from your toes up - to increase blood return to the heart. Start by pointing toes (entire foot) down then up a few times, rotate your ankles, stretch your legs, bend your knees, squeeze your knees together, push them apart against resistance, etc. If you're on your back, roll over once or twice and back again. Then see if all that helped.

If this only happens in the morning, keep water by your bed and drink a couple of glasses of water (about 16 oz) before getting up (ideally up to 30 minutes before), and elevate the head of your bed.

Get enough exercise.

There are a lot of medical causes of dizziness on standing as well. Because of your age and how long this has been going on, one would need to do a few tests to see if your nervous system is slow to respond to sudden changes in cardiac output (this is called autonomic dysfunction).

If this is bothersome enough, a more in-depth evaluation should be done. Only a good exam by a doctor can tell if it is significant enough to warrant further investigation. If you're unhappy with your doctor's approach, get a second opinion.

Above all, take @DoctorWhom's advice in her comment.

<sub>the paper below discusses some scary things. Please keep in mind that due to your age, you're unlikely to have many of these conditions.</sub>

<sub>[Preventing and treating orthostatic hypotension: As easy as A, B, C](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2888469/)</sub>

Comment: "Drink a couple of glasses of water before getting up ideally up to 30 minutes before" = stay in bed for 30 minutes after waking up. :/ What if you have a life?

Comment: If people have really bad dizziness (like falling down dizzy), this could save you a nasty gash on the head. Just a suggestion; no one has to do it. :)